# Trying to send specified values as FormData with Jquery sends ?[object%20FormData]

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I'm trying to send some FormData via a simple jquery ajax `GET/Post` but for some reason my formData is not getting set right. I end up with `?[object%20FormData]` as my payload.

I'm a bit new to this FormData stuff, but I was able to use it successfully with file uploads no problem using this same technique... Here's what I'm doing with my specified values I want to send:

I should note: I'm not using any `form` element to grab these values from.

```
var data = new FormData();
        data.append("date", curDate);
        data.append("serviceID", sID);
        data.append("attSummID", asID);
        data.append("totalCount", 0);
        data.append("visitorCount",0);
        data.append("reset",false);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/4DACTION/WEB_ServiceCounts/',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
```

Any tips?

Comment: are your input field ids curDate, sID, asID? then, if you want their values you have to use: $("#curDate").val() ...

Comment: Have you tried removing `contentType: false`?  If you're using `FormData`, I think the default `contentType` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` is appropriate?

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle those are declared variables that I am setting. I was under the impression you could just reference variables like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @JamesThorpe this post seems to lead me to believe that I need that there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery Also, if I take it out I get an error.

Comment: You have to pass your form to the constructor then .. like this: new FormData($("#formId");

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle I'm not using a form. I'm just assigning declared variable values as formData.

Comment: @btbJosh ok - wasn't sure if that was just when you were sending files - what error do you get without it?

Comment: how do you declare them?

Comment: @JamesThorpe `Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
URL: http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js
Line Number: 5`

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle I really don't think that's relevent as I get the same results if I explicitly type a string into the "value" argument of the `.append()` method.

Comment: Have you tried it as a `POST` instead of `GET` at all?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm trying to handle server-side logic differently based on whether it is a `POST` or a `GET` so I would prefer to use them this way if possible... But it does seem to construct the payload properly on a `POST`

Comment: ok - just wondering if due to how jQuery handles an ajax request, it may always be trying to convert the `data` parameter to something it can put on the query string for the `GET`.

Comment: I think you're right... Which means I need to restructure my server code. :(

Comment: 1) If you use `GET` then you don't need FormData at all 2) Instead of FormData you could send an object instead that looks like so `data : { key : val , foo : bar }`